# Throw an Error in an MSBuild Task

Tags: msbuild

How do you throw an error from within an MSBuild task and force the build to fail. Something like:

```
<Task>
  <ThrowError Condition="$(SomeCondition)" Message="There was a problem with the build" />
</Task>
```

Comment: Agree with the below answers.  You might want to keep the MSBuild task reference in your bookmarks folder as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [Error Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx)

```
<Error Condition="$(SomeCondition)" Text="There was a problem with the build" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Error-task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx) would do the trick.

```
<Error
            Text="errormessage"
            Condition="errorcondition" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Error instead of ThrowError ? It works for me ;)